# Websphere remote EJB client lookup returning NPE

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I have a remote EJB packed in a `war` and deployed in `Websphere 8.5`.

My client code looks like below

```
public class WASClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try { 
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

            env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", 
                    "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
            env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop:localhost:2809");

            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
            Object obj = ctx.lookup("StudentService");
            StudentService service = (StudentService) obj;

            System.out.println("EJB Output -> " + bean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I added EJB thin client and orb jars in my classpath.

From admin console I went to my deployed war, went into EJB jndi name and gave the EJB look up name as StudentService.

Disabled administrative security, restarted websphere and ran my client code and it returned NPE.

I then created stubs for the ejbs using createEJBStubs tool. Redeployed the war and rested my client code. It still returned NPE.

To make sure my EJB lookup is working fine, I added a web service resource class in my war and looked up the EJB from the web service and it ran fine.

I added sas and ssl files to the env properties and ran the client choice and it still returned NPE.

I also added

```
env.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");
```

But still it returned NPE.

I cross checked the port number also. I can see in server logs that rmi is running on port 2809.

What am I doing wrong??

P.S
When I tried to print obj it printed some remote_stubxxxxxx....

To make sure lookup is working fine, I changed the lookup name to some invalid name and my code ran into exceptions.

Comment: Adding the generated stubs to my classpath resolved the issue.